# Run shell command on S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a debian repository on S3 and I want to run `dpkg-scanpackages` on all the `.deb` files in a certain folder. This will generate a file called `Packages.gz`.

For example, the command `dpkg-scanpackages -m . | gzip -c > Packages.gz` will generate a `Packages.gz` file.

How can I do this on an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you **can't do this directly** on Amazon S3 as it is an object storage system, not a regular filesystem.

However, you can use third part tools to simulate access to S3 as if it was regular filesystem. A popular such tool is [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse):

> s3fs allows Linux and macOS to **mount an S3 bucket via FUSE**. s3fs preserves the native object format for files, allowing use of other tools like AWS CLI.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Lambda? I'm using Elastic Beanstalk and having dynamic files (in this instance an entire S3 bucket) isn't the best idea

Comment: @docyoda Unfortunately you can't do this in lambda. But lambda now [supports EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/), thus maybe you could store your files in EFS instead of S3?